# Pass data between siblings without Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Consider the following component tree

```
<Header />
 <SearchBar />
<ProductList />
 <Product />
```

In the `SearchBar` component I want to catch the value of an input and send that value to `ProductList` to dynamically render `Product` components based on the value received.

Is there a way to communicate between `SearchBar` and `ProductList` without the need of a component that wraps both of them or without Redux ?

Comment: Use state store into state and use another component.

Comment: @OsmanGoniNahid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Maybe you are asking without using redux passing data between component in under same root, I mean how u mentioned. 
So you can use state. for saving the value and getting value from other component.

Answer (score 2):

According to React's page "React is all about one-way data flow down the component hierarchy" which means that data passing horizontally should be avoided.

In your case you could have a parent component that render `<SearchBar/>` and `<ProductList/>`based on state. For example, whenever the user enter with a value in `<SearchBar>` it changes the state on the parent component, and consequently `<ProductList>` will be rendered again.

Answer (score 0):

As Osman said, you could pass the value of the SearchBar into a state and then from the state into the Product using a function.

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        newProduct: event.currentTarget.value
    )}
}

render() {
    return(
        <SearchBar onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Product content={this.state.newProduct} />
    );
}
```

Make sure you don't forget to bind the function in the constructor.